# Question about ManipulatePlot3D. for 2-D Wave Equation in Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, visualization

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
c = 1;
L = 1;

(*Definition of functions  f (x, y) and g (x, y)*)

f[x_, y_] := x*y (1 - x)*(1 - y)
g[x_, y_] := 0
\[Mu][n_] = (n*\[Pi])^2;
\[Kappa][m_] = (m*\[Pi])^2;
\[Lambda][n_, m_] = \[Mu][n] + \[Kappa][m];
\[Omega][n_, m_] = c*Sqrt[\[Lambda][n, m]  ] // Simplify
U[n_, m_] = Sin[(n*\[Pi]*x)/L]*Sin[(m*\[Pi]*y)/L]

(*Computation of the Fourier coefficients*)
A[n_, m_] = 4/L^2 \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(L\)]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(L\)]f[x, y]*
     U[n, m] \[DifferentialD]x \[DifferentialD]y\)\)

B[n_, m_] = 4/(L^2*\[Omega][n, m]) \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(L\)]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(L\)]g[x, y]*
     U[n, m] \[DifferentialD]x \[DifferentialD]y\)\)

(The general solution for T*)

T[n_, m_] = 
 A[n, m]*Cos[\[Omega][n, m]*t] + B[n, m]*Sin[\[Omega][n, m]*t]

(*The general solution of our problem*)

u1[x, y, 
  t] = (A[n, m]*Cos[\[Omega][n, m]*t] + 
    B[n, m]*Sin[\[Omega][n, m]*t])*Sin[(n*\[Pi]*x)/L]*
  Sin[(m*\[Pi]*y)/L]

u[x_, y_, t_, l_, k_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(l\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(k\)]
\*FractionBox[\(16\ \((\(-1\) + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(m\)])\)\ \((\(-1\) + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(n\)])\)\ Cos[
\*SqrtBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\)]\ \[Pi]\ t]\ Sin[
\*FractionBox[\(n\ \[Pi]\ x\), \(L\)]]\ Sin[
\*FractionBox[\(m\ \[Pi]\ y\), \(L\)]]\), \(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(3\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(3\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(6\)]\)]\)\)

(*We calculate the partial sum (k,l)=(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3) *)
u[x, y, t, 1, 1] // TraditionalForm
u[x, y, t, 1, 2] // TraditionalForm
u[x, y, t, 2, 2] // TraditionalForm
u[x, y, t, 3, 3] // TraditionalForm

(*we plot snapshots for the last case*)
graphs = 
  Table[ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, u[x, y, t, 3, 3]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 
     3}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> 600, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
    ColorFunction -> "MintColors", PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 2, 1/
    4}];
p1 = Partition[graphs, 3];
Show[GraphicsGrid[p1]]
```

[image]

Now using the command manipulate we have the following

```
u[x_, y_, t_, l_, k_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(l\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(k\)]
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(3\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(3\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(6\)]\)] 4\ Cos[
\*SqrtBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\)]\ \[Pi]\ t]\ \((\(-2\) + 
     2\ Cos[m\ \[Pi]] + m\ \[Pi]\ Sin[m\ \[Pi]])\)\ \((\(-2\) + 
     2\ Cos[n\ \[Pi]] + n\ \[Pi]\ Sin[n\ \[Pi]])\)\ Sin[
    n\ \[Pi]\ x]\ Sin[m\ \[Pi]\ y]\)\)
Manipulate[
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, u[x, y, t, 3, 3]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}, {-7, 7}}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
 ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", Mesh -> True, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1 , 1}], {t, 0, 10, 0.0001}]
```

[image]

Now the paper [Partial Differential Equations:
The Wave Equation In Two Dimensions](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5df2d0395ce1d42fd6b23c1a/t/5df6b7e11bd90e41f951f9c3/1576450026933/12-2D_Wave_Equation_Stroupe.pdf) which I am studying gives the following solution

[image]
[image]

Why do I receive different outputs for the Manipulate?
What is my mistake?

Comment: Check the scale of your z-axis.  You are forcing `{-7, 7}` but that is too wide. If you are uncertain then use `Automatic` instead of `{-7, 7}` or analytically examine the min and max z over the domain of `t`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you don't need to specify the x & y ranges in the `PlotRange` option as you are keeping these to the range of these parameters specified for the plot.  You only need it for the z-axis to keep it from skipping around as `t` varies.  So only something like `{Automatic, Automatic, {-.1, .1}}` is nessesary.

Comment: @Edmund could you show me, please? because I have made the changes as you said above, now the Manipulate works but still does not give the result as the papers show

Comment: @Edmund Thank you for the assistance and thank you in advance if you will show me how it works correct

Comment: `PlotRange->{Automatic, Automatic, {-.1, .1}}`